# Vim command to insert blank line in normal mode

Tags: vim, insert

Is there any command in Vim that will do the same thing as `o` or `O` (insert a blank line before/after the current one), but which doesn't also switch into insert mode?

Comment: You could just map it to a key of your choice like this article suggests: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_newline_without_entering_insert_mode. I dunno if there's a built in key for it though.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14746/vi-command-for-adding-blank-line

Comment: Hmm. Is there some way to close a question as a dup of something on a different site?

Answer (score 18):

```
:nnoremap <silent> [<space> :pu! _<cr>:']+1<cr>
:nnoremap <silent> ]<space> :pu _<cr>:'[-1<cr>
```

Explanation:

- `:put` will paste a register linewise below. (`:pu!` above)
- `:pu _` will paste the blackhole register, which is empty so we get a blank line
- `'[` and `']` marks are set at the start and end of a changed or yanked text.
- `:'[` will move the cursor to the starting line of the last change (the put in this case)
- `:'[-1` will move the `'[` but up one more line

If you prefer a plugin then I suggest Tim Pope's [unimpaired.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590). Which supplies these mappings, but will also take a count. The plugin also has many other nice mappings.

Comment: I was going to mention unimpaired too.  Great set up mappings.

Answer (score 1):

In insert mode:

```
:normal O
```

From vim inline manual:

> Execute Normal mode commands {commands}.  This makes          it possible to
>   execute Normal mode commands typed on             the command-line.  {commands}
>   are executed like they            are typed.  For undo all commands are undone
>   together.             Execution stops when an error is encountered.           If the
>   [!] is given, mappings will not be used.          {commands} should be a
>   complete command.  If             {commands} does not finish a command, the
>   last one          will be aborted as if  or  was typed.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal

I got the hint there:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16452/7914

Comment: This appears to be the opposite of what the question was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
:map <c-j> o<esc>
```

this is: when you press *control + j* it will add a line below (and go to insert mode) and then switch back to normal mode if you want to stay in the same line you where before just add a `k` at the end, something like this:

```
:map <c-j> o<esc>k
```

I also added a *control + k* to add a line before the one I's standing on

```
:map <c-k> O<esc>
```

and  just like the one before you can add a `j` at the end to stay on the same line:

```
:map <c-k> O<esc>j
```

If you need or want something more advanced you can check this posts:
[Quickly adding and deleting empty lines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Quickly_adding_and_deleting_empty_lines) or [Insert newline without entering insert mode](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_newline_without_entering_insert_mode)

Answer (score -1):

dd on a blank line, p to restore it, and then p where you want the blank line(s)

Comment: If you were to be on a blank line why not hit `yy` instead.  Then no need to restore it.

Comment: That's an overkill. `o<esc>` and then hitting `.` as many times as we need will achieve the same result.

Comment: Or add a count: `o<esc>5.` for 6 blank lines (including the first one added by `o`), for example.