# Is there any way to insert a space in normal mode?

Tags: vim

I'm just starting to use vim.

I would like to know if there is a simple default key binding that will allow me to add a space in normal mode.

If not what is the next best alternative?

Comment: If you're going to _insert_ something, the best mode for that is the _insert_ mode.

Comment: @sidyll right, but some operations seem favored by the vim devs (ie. >> works from normal mode).  You don't know how many times I've wished there was a built-in shortcut for "i<space><esc>" so I can save those 2 seconds.  More than utility, it's just annoying to not be able to automatically do this with out-of-the-box vim.  What if I have to ssh into a GCloud VM and can't easily include my .vimrc?  Every little step higher the activation energy is to getting things done becomes, the less I'll feel like getting things done

Comment: @frank I respect your vision. I think it's part of Vim simplicity to be like that, though. The `>>` isn't necessarily a space inserter, it's a indentation command which depends on other settings. For the space inserting case in particular, I think it is left out of the built-in commands due to not being so popular in relation to the other commands (basically every key already is a command, so adding another one requires trading off one by another). You can always type a quick map if you're going to do it many times, over a ssh session. Or do it once and repeat where needed with `.`

Comment: @sidyll I like how you wrote "I'm just starting to use VIM" so I thought you were a beginner and then I'm like "Oh, that was in 2012.  This guy is probably 3x as good as me now; he can probably answer his own question."  Btw, I end up using `.` a hell of a lot

Comment: @sidyll I also realized I almost always copy over my .vimrc to a new computer to get `jj` as `<esc>` anyway, so I may as well not complain too much :P

Comment: @frank I think who wrote that was the original asker, not me :) About copying your vimrc, yes that is what I generally do too: scp it over. I also recommend keeping a copy of your dotfiles somewhere you can access remotely. You can put it under source control. So if you ever face the task of operating on a server not from your computer, you have a remote backup of your current config. Regarding esc, I switched places of caps lock and esc keys on my computer to match the old layout. esc is much more important than caps... BTW I think I started using vim daily in ~2010, while in high school :)

Comment: @sidyll haha, oops.  Anyway, no need to turn SOverflow answer into a chat.  Sometimes I go on this chatroom: (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166968/the-ai-hub).  Certainly Zoey could use a little company :P

Comment: @sidyll "If you're going to insert something, the best mode for that is the insert mode." This is not the general, always consistent rule im vim. For example 'o' and 'O' insert LF themselves (without a user explicit action of typing it) whereas the LF is basically another normal character. Why do they do it? Because LF is so common character that it's convenient to combine such an action within a single vim command. Would it be equally justified for the <space> as even much more common character than LF? Of course it would.

Comment: People who find this useful will probably also be interested in [Vim command to insert blank line in normal mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765211/vim-command-to-insert-blank-line-in-normal-mode).

Answer (score 50):

```
:nnoremap space i<space><esc>
```

Then, any time you type <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> in normal mode, it'll insert a space at the cursor.

Or you could just hit <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.

OK, OK. If you really want to use the space bar in normal, add `<>` to the above.

```
:nnoremap <space> i<space><esc>
```

Comment: When you add this command to your `.vimrc`, make sure there is no whitespace at the end of the line. Else, something weird is going to happen!!

Comment: `nnoremap <Space> i<Space><Right><ESC>` moves the cursor along with the newly inserted space.

Comment: nice one. the first joke made in an answer on stack overflow (saw by myself, ofc)

Comment: just curious who would type s p a c e to get a space ;)

Answer (score 12):

If you yank a space and then hit p (put) while in normal mode, I suppose that would work. Or if you write a space in insert mode, then hit . while in normal mode (repeat action)

Comment: This is what I do all the time

Answer (score 10):

I use `ss` to insert a space in normal mode

and add the following sentence to .vimrc

```
nnoremap ss i<space><esc>
```

Comment: -1 : fyi single s is a useful vim command from normal mode.  It's like 'x' followed by 'i'.  I would not do this.  But the general idea of remapping is a great one!  :)

Answer (score 9):

Insert a space after the cursor:

```
a<space><esc>
```

Before:

```
i<space><Esc>
```

Replace the character under the cursor with a space:

```
r<space>
```

Comment: -1 : The OP pretty clearly asked for not this.  Maybe this answer is useful to beginners, but this is exactly the opposite of the way the OP's question is worded.  -1

Answer (score 6):

You could always just `yank` a space from somewhere in the document and `paste` it...

Answer (score 5):

You could create a macro. To create a macro type `q` followed by any letter in the normal mode. Thus to create a macro with the name `x` you would type `qx`. Then all you need is to enter into the insert mode type space and escape back to the normal mode. Once you are done type `q` to save the macro. From here every time you want to insert a space in the normal mode type `@x`.

The keystrokes: `qxi <Esc>q`

Comment: We're really looking for the 'one-keystroke-out-of-the-box vim' approach.  I think most of us just use `.` when we want to indent a lot of code anyway.  Appreciate the alternative way of doing it, though :)

Answer (score 2):

As `:nnoremap <space> i<space><Esc>` will add a new space on the right hand of the cursor, You can try `:nnoremap <space> i<space><Esc>l`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the first line in your code block (using navigation keys)
2. Press “shift + v” (to enter Visual mode)
3. Press “j” (or “down arrow”) to select the lines in the block which you wish to indent.
4. Press “shift + >” to right indent, alternatively, press “shift + <” to left indent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).