# Map <C-CR> in vim

Tags: vim

Attempting to add a normal mode mapping in vim for Control + Enter to insert line break above cursor positon

`:nmap <C-CR> O<Esc>`

I am finding this does not work - what am I missing here?

Comment: Alternative to a common problem: [Vim command to insert blank line in normal mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765211/vim-command-to-insert-blank-line-in-normal-mode/6765349)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably based on your terminal rather than vim.  You can tell what key your terminal sends by `<C-Enter>` via <kbd>C-V C-Enter</kbd>.  Most likely this is a newline which you can use as `<NL>` in vim.

```
:nmap <NL> O<Esc>
```

Comment: When I run the keyboard command above, i get back '^M' - what exactly is this

Comment: Pretty sure that `^M` is `<CR>` so you can just give that a try, but I think that is just <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well.  Are you using windows?

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today; though this particular mapping should work in GVIM, but not in most terminals. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>non-alphabetic</kbd> cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated [various proposals](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8).

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.