# Inserting two new lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to do this with a Vim command?

[] = Cursor Normal Mode

[ = Cursor Insert Mode

Before

```
Text []
```

After

```
Text

[
```

Before

```
Text []
```

After

```
[

Text
```

Comment: This is related to a commonly asked question: [Vim command to insert blank line in normal mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6765211/438329)

Answer (score 11):

I've changed the `[count]` behavior of `o` / `O` with the following mapping. I think this does what you want:

```
" o/O                   Start insert mode with [count] blank lines.
"                       The default behavior repeats the insertion [count]
"                       times, which is not so useful.
function! s:NewLineInsertExpr( isUndoCount, command )
    if ! v:count
        return a:command
    endif

    let l:reverse = { 'o': 'O', 'O' : 'o' }
    " First insert a temporary '$' marker at the next line (which is necessary
    " to keep the indent from the current line), then insert <count> empty lines
    " in between. Finally, go back to the previously inserted temporary '$' and
    " enter insert mode by substituting this character.
    " Note: <C-\><C-n> prevents a move back into insert mode when triggered via
    " |i_CTRL-O|.
    return (a:isUndoCount && v:count ? "\<C-\>\<C-n>" : '') .
    \   a:command . "$\<Esc>m`" .
    \   v:count . l:reverse[a:command] . "\<Esc>" .
    \   'g``"_s'
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <expr> o <SID>NewLineInsertExpr(1, 'o')
nnoremap <silent> <expr> O <SID>NewLineInsertExpr(1, 'O')
```

Answer (score 6):

do these two mapping help?

```
nnoremap <leader>O O<ESC>O
nnoremap <leader>o o<cr>
```

the first `by pressing <leader>O` will add two empty lines above current line, and bring you to INSERT mode. The 2nd one `by pressing <leader>o` will add two lines after your current.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was just curious why there wasn't something like 2o or 2O in Vim.

Comment: @alexchenco there really are `2o and 2O`, but they don't do what you expect. press `2o or 2O` and then `<esc>` to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants a solution in Lua for Neovim:

```
local new_lines = function(command, opposite)
    if vim.v.count <= 1 then
        return command
    end

    return ":<C-u><CR>" .. command .. ".<Esc>m`" .. vim.v.count - 1 .. opposite .. "<Esc>g``s"
end

vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "o", function() return new_lines("o", "O") end, { noremap = true, silent = true, expr = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "O", function() return new_lines("O", "o") end, { noremap = true, silent = true, expr = true })
```